# JavaScript file not found if I use sub-resource in Jersey's @Path annotation

Tags: java, javascript, url, servlets, jersey

I have a Jersey REST web service and here is my resource class for the URL path `http://localhost:8080/myapp/account/home`.

```
@Path("account/home")
public class AccountResources {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Viewable displayForm() {
        return new Viewable("/homepage.html");
    }
}
```

The HTML file `homepage.html` is linked with a JavaScript file which should be loaded from `js/jump.js` on the server:

```
<script src="js/jump.js"></script>
```

However, when I launched my webapp and opened `http://localhost:8080/myapp/account/home` (basically this is `homepage.html`), the JavaScript file `js/jump.js` is not loaded. So I had to add the context root path `/myapp/` to make it work:

```
<script src="/myapp/js/jump.js"></script>
```

This is not pretty since the context root path `/myapp` can be changed later. So I don't want to add `/myapp` everywhere in my HTML files. Also, the physical directory layout in my webapp is as follows:

```
WebContent
    |
    |_____ homepage.html
    |
    |_____ js
            |
            |____ jump.js
```

So why it doesn't work if I use `<script src="js/jump.js"></script>` in `homepage.html` even though physically `js/jump.js` and `homepage.html` are in the same web root directory on the server? Does Jersey servlet change the relative URL path of HTML and JavaScript files if I use `@Path` annotation in that way? I tried another way of using `@Path` without subresource:

```
@Path("account")
```

This time I can use `<script src="js/jump.js"></script>` in my `homepage.html` and the JS file can be loaded successfully if I open `http://localhost:8080/myapp/account`. So it seems that subresource in the URL path defined in Jersey's `@Path("account/home")` annotation will make the JavaScript relative file path unsearchable.

Any good way to make both happy? (i.e., I can use both subresource in URL path like `@Path("account/home")`  without changing `js/jump.js` to `/myapp/js/jump.js`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing

```
<script src="../js/jump.js"></script>
```

On your first example the server evaluates the relative path to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/account/js/jump.js`

but what you need is:

`http://localhost:8080/myapp/js/jump.js`

So just let the browser know to look up one path up.
Good luck!

Comment: Magic! This works fine. But isn't it a bit strange because physically the HTML file `homepage.html` is at the same directory level as `js` folder under the same web root directory `WebContent` on the server. Why does the server evaluate the relative path differently?

Comment: It does not matter where homepage.html is on the server. URL wise, it is on myapp/account/home. And the js is on myapp/js/jump.js. Relative path remove last word after last / and concat the new path. So you need to get rid of the account path.